# Django tried using these urls... empty path didnt match any of these

Tags: django

Not sure why can't django find the empty path, I included the app path to the project's urls, I added path "" to the app's urls.py. so what's wrong here

Here is the code for my app

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world!")
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("",views.index,name="index")
]
```

the project's url.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('pricelist/',include("pricelist.urls"))
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty path `""` is not mapped to any view in your app. To fix that change this line

```
path('pricelist/',include("pricelist.urls"))
```

To

```
path('',include("pricelist.urls"))
```